create loop to read multiple .txt files from a list
I am trying to extract relevant information from .txt files where the output is an excel table with the necessary information collected in relevant columns. Since the .txt file is converted from a html file, I have to use steps to clean the information I need into a dataframe. I can do this with one file and now I want to use a loop to loop through each file in the folder and extract the information as per my code and then save it as an excel table!
Here is the code which works for a single file from the folder:
# list all the file names of the specified pattern 
fnames <- list.files(path = paste0(wd,"09_data_tables/Raster_layer_statistics"),full.names = T)
#view(fnames)

# read .txt files and extract relevant information into data table

  my_tibble <- read_delim(XX.txt,delim = ":", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                          trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 1)
  
  # convert tibble to dataframe
  my_df <- as.data.frame(my_tibble)
  
  # remove characters from column 1
  my_df$X1 <- gsub('<p>', '', my_df$X1)
  
  # remove characters from column 2
  my_df$X2 <- str_sub(my_df$X2, end = -5)
  
  # renames columns on 'my_df'
  colnames(my_df) <- c("Attribute", "Value","X")
  
  # copy column 3 information to column 2 of first row
  my_df[1,3] <-substring(my_df[1,3],61)
  my_df[1,3] <- gsub("\\..*","",my_df[1,3])
  my_df[1,2] <- my_df[1,3]
  my_df <- my_df[,1:2]
  str(my_df)
  
  my_df_wide <- my_df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Attribute, values_from = Value)
  
  # Check columns classes
  sapply(my_df_wide, class)
  
  # convert character to numeric for all columns with numbers
  cols <- names(my_df_wide)[2:9]
  my_df_wide[cols] <- lapply(my_df_wide[cols], as.numeric)
  my_df_wide <- as.data.frame(my_df_wide)
  my_df_wide$Flight <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", my_df_wide$`Analyzed file`))
  my_df_wide$`Analyzed file` <- sub("^[^_]*_", "", my_df_wide$`Analyzed file`)
  

# write dataframe to excel table
write_xlsx(my_df_wide,"10_results/raster_layer_statistics.xlsx")


I would use a list rather than a loop for this.

First create a function with filename as parameter which reads this file and creates a data frame. (I've pretty much left your code unchanged here apart from using the filename parameter instead of XX.txt.
use lapply to apply this to all your files and create a list of data frames
add names
use write_xlsx to write this entire list. Each data frame gets its own tab

NOTE: I'm assuming your text file names will work as valid excel sheet names, if not you'll have to process the sheet_names variable a bit.
Also, apologies in advance for any typos - without a reproducible example it's hard to be sure I've gotten it exactly right.
# list all the file names of the specified pattern 
fnames <- list.files(path = paste0(wd,"09_data_tables/Raster_layer_statistics"),full.names = T)
#view(fnames)

# repeat without folders to get sheet names
sheet_names <- list.files(path = paste0(wd,"09_data_tables/Raster_layer_statistics"),full.names = FALSE)

# function to read one file
read_one_txt <- function(filename) {
  my_tibble <- read_delim(filename, delim = ":", escape_double = FALSE, col_names = FALSE, 
                          trim_ws = TRUE, skip = 1)
  
  # convert tibble to dataframe
  my_df <- as.data.frame(my_tibble)
  
  # remove characters from column 1
  my_df$X1 <- gsub('<p>', '', my_df$X1)
  
  # remove characters from column 2
  my_df$X2 <- str_sub(my_df$X2, end = -5)
  
  # renames columns on 'my_df'
  colnames(my_df) <- c("Attribute", "Value","X")
  
  # copy column 3 information to column 2 of first row
  my_df[1,3] <-substring(my_df[1,3],61)
  my_df[1,3] <- gsub("\\..*","",my_df[1,3])
  my_df[1,2] <- my_df[1,3]
  my_df <- my_df[,1:2]
  str(my_df)
  
  my_df_wide <- my_df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = Attribute, values_from = Value)
  
  # Check columns classes
  sapply(my_df_wide, class)
  
  # convert character to numeric for all columns with numbers
  cols <- names(my_df_wide)[2:9]
  my_df_wide[cols] <- lapply(my_df_wide[cols], as.numeric)
  my_df_wide <- as.data.frame(my_df_wide)
  my_df_wide$Flight <- as.numeric(gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "\\1", my_df_wide$`Analyzed file`))
  my_df_wide$`Analyzed file` <- sub("^[^_]*_", "", my_df_wide$`Analyzed file`)
  return(my_df_wide)
}

# apply this to the list of filenames
all_data_frames <- lapply(fnames, read_one_txt)

# add the names
names(all_data_frames) <- sheet_names

# write dataframes to excel table
write_xlsx(all_data_frames, "10_results/raster_layer_statistics.xlsx")


Hi, thanks you for suggesting this! Unfortunately when I apply this modified code nothing happens, the function does not seem to be working. I am new to asking for help in r code so I don't know what other information I could provide you to help solve this issue!

If possible, could you share a small example of the format of one of the .txt files, and a sample of the resulting data (head(my_tibble, 20) and head(my_df_wide, 20)?

I see that I was missing a } at the end of the function definition. It's now in the code.

I already added the missing '}' I converted 'fnames' to a list from a character vector and that seems to have done the trick and the code works now and does what I need! Thanks for your help ;-)
